# Cannot add component in draft state Editor role

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

If I have an item in draft state and I go to Experience Editor, the add new component is disabled and I cannot add any new components for an Editor role.

Any idea where should I look?

Comment: Are you logged in as an Administrator or a non-administrator? Was this working before and did it stop working? There is a specific role you need to be able to add components to the page in EE. I believe it is "Sitecore Client Designing". If you can manage roles, try giving your user this role. Otherwise, ask your Sitecore administrator to give your user this role.

Comment: It works for administrator role. But I have created a Content Editor role that is a member of Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing , Designer and Author. On each item I have a workflow. When the item is in Draft state I cannot add any components in Experience Editor

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like member Roles are the issue here.
Look into including one of the  **Designer** roles (`Designer` / `Sitecore Client Designing`)

From [Sitecore security roles documentation:](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles)

> **Sitecore Client Designing**
>
> Gives the user access to Experience Editor Design pane features that allow a user to set layout details associated with items in the Sitecore client.
>
> Members of this role are: Designer

and

> **Designer**
>
> Gives the user read and write access to the areas of the content tree
> that are required when changing layout details for individual items
> and groups of items via template standard values, as well as items
> required when configuring the Experience Editor Design Pane.
>
> This role also has two of the Sitecore Client roles assigned to it, so
> if you assign just this role to a user, the Sitecore Client Designing
> and Sitecore Client Users roles will be automatically assigned to the
> user.
>
> This role provides access to the Experience Editor Design Pane
> features and the designer options in the Content Editor.
> Note This role is not a member of the Author and Authoring roles, so
> it does not allow users to edit items.
>
> Members of this role are:  Developer

Comment: I missed that @DougCouto referenced this in the comments on the question but, as i  ended up here on this un-answered question - others will too. Therefore, i'll not retract this answer as it resolved my issue and, hopefully, it will be useful to others as well.

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like a a workflow security issue. I would recommend using the Access Viewer to check the user's access to the item you are trying to edit. If it tells you that there is no access, the right side of the tool should tell you why. If the 'why' is workflow state access, you probably need to adjust your security on the Workflow state for 'Draft'.